# Backbone JST Template with Partials not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I read about JST Templates and Partials in [Backbone Patterns](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/) and was trying to implement with my project.
Here is my code of template:
I am using Backbone js with Underscore js and CoffeeScript -

```
App.Abc.JST = {}
App.Abc.JST['person/contact'] = _.template '''
  <h4>Something</h4><a href="dev.app.com/<%= itemTemplate() %>"><%= itemTemplate() %></a>
  <b><%= itemTemplate() %></b>
'''

itemTemplate: _.template '''
  Common Code here
'''
```

I am getting error : `itemTemplate is not defined`.
Am i doing something wrong?. Thanks for your time.

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrote that, i have edited my question.

Comment: So how are you trying to use use `App.Abc.JST['person/contact']`? What arguments do you supply to that function?

Comment: @muistooshort - i am passing the `model properties` in this, anyways i end up doing `<%= App.Abc.JST['itemTemplate']()%> and App.Abc.JST['itemTemplate'] : _.template ''' #Common Code'''`
instead of above code and it worked fine. I guess mixing JST with Partials caused problem.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways i end up doing :

```
App.Abc.JST = {}
App.Abc.JST['person/contact'] = _.template '''
  <h4>Something</h4><a href="dev.app.com/<%= App.Abc.JST['itemTemplate']() %>"><%= App.Abc.JST['itemTemplate']() %></a>
  <b><%= App.Abc.JST['itemTemplate']() %></b>
'''

App.Abc.JST['itemTemplate']: _.template '''
  Common Code here
'''
```

And it worked fine, i guess mixing JST with Partials causes problem.